# moderncv pagenumbers with 2 pages

Tags: page-numbering, moderncv

I got a question about `moderncv` and `pagenumbering`.

In the following example, there is on the 1st page no footer and no pagenumbering, on the 2nd page its there. I want on the 1st page ONLY the pagenumber, on the 2nd page the standard footer and pagenumbering.

How is it possible?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}

% content
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\pagestyle{empty}

\section{Education}
\cventry{1998-2007}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}    {Description}

\pagebreak % just to simulate a lenghty CV for this MWE

\section{Computer skills}
Second page

\thispagestyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You have a `\pagestyle` and a `\thispagestyle` command. You should check what they do and which styles result in which design. I am using them to seldom to provide an answer, but it should not be too hard to find information on that.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is solved by adding

```
\fancypagestyle{first}{%
\cfoot{}
}
```

to the preamble.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Not required here as it is used by moderncv anyway
\fancypagestyle{first}{%
\cfoot{}
}

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}

% content
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\thispagestyle{first}

\section{Education}
\cventry{1998-2007}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}
{Description}

\pagebreak % just to simulate a lenghty CV for this MWE

\section{Computer skills}
Second page

\thispagestyle{plain}
\end{document}
```